# Como fazer soma de uma coluna no R

Tags: r, sum

Estou utilizando uma base de dados com várias datas e gostaria de fazer a soma dos valores da última data disponível, consigo filtrar o `data.frame` pela data, mas não consigo realizar a soma dos valores, estou tentando utilizar a função `colSums`.

Link da base de dados utilizada em csv: https://covid.saude.gov.br/

Código que estou usando:

```
library(tidyverse)

dados <- read_delim("~/Downloads/arquivo_geral.csv", 
                                        ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
dados <- dados[,-c(1,4,6)]

soma <- dados %>%
  filter(data == max(dados$data)) %>%
  select(-grep("obitosAcumulados", colnames(dados))) %>%
  colSums(dados[3])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta inserir a função `summarize`:

```
library(tidyverse)

dados %>%
  filter(data == max(dados$data)) %>%
  select(-grep("obitosAcumulados", colnames(dados))) %>%
  summarise(var = colSums(dados[3]))

# A tibble: 1 x 1
#      var
#    <dbl>
# 1 550237
```

E, se objetivo é apenas somar a coluna, não é preciso criar um objeto (`soma`) para isso.

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizar colSums() ou rowSums() nesse caso não funcionaria, pois de acordo com a documentação da função, os objetos devem possuir duas ou mais dimensões...Então, quando você tenta passar o array da coluna obitosAcumulados, você está colocando como input um série (um objeto com uma única dimensão).

Consegui chegar ao resultado que vc busca fazendo o seguinte:

```
require(dplyr)

df <- read.csv('Seu Diretório\\seu_arquivo.csv', sep = ';')

# Utilizei o arquivo do link que enviou.

soma <- df %>% 
  select(data, obitosAcumulados) %>% 
  filter(data == '2020-04-22') # Para esta linha de código funcionar, a coluna data 
                               # precisa ser um Fator.

soma <- sum(soma$obitosAcumulados)  # O resultado será o total somado de todas
                                    # as ocorrências do dia utilizado como filtro.
```

Espero ter ajudado a atingir o resultado esperado, avisa se conseguiu resolver.
Qualquer dúvida chama novamente.

Comment: Obrigado pela solução, funcionou perfeitamente!